# Running 2 consecutive Scrapy CrawlerProcess from script with different settings

Tags: python, scrapy

I have 2 different `Scrapy` spiders currently working when launched with:

```
scrapy crawl spidername -o data\whatever.json
```

Of course I know I can use a system call from the script to replicate just that command, but I would prefer sticking to `CrawlerProcess` usage or any other method of making it work from a script.

The thing is: as read in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468275/running-scrapy-from-a-script-with-file-output) (and also in Scrapy docs), I have to set the output file in the settings given to the `CrawlerProcess` constructor:

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
'FEED_URI': 'data.json'
})
```

The problem is that I don't want both spiders to be storing data into the same output file, but two different files. So my first attempt was obviously creating a new `CrawlerProcess` with different settings when the first job is done:

```
session_date_format = '%Y%m%d'
session_date = datetime.now().strftime(session_date_format)

try:
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': os.path.join('data', 'an_origin', '{}.json'.format(session_date)),
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
        'LOG_STDOUT': True,
        'LOG_FILE': 'scrapy_log.txt',
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
        'RETRY_ENABLED': True,
        'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 503, 504, 400, 404, 408],
        'RETRY_TIMES': 5
    })
    process.crawl(MyFirstSpider)
    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
except Exception as e:
    print('ERROR while crawling: {}'.format(e))
else:
    print('Data successfuly crawled')

time.sleep(3)  # Wait 3 seconds

try:
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': os.path.join('data', 'other_origin', '{}.json'.format(session_date)),
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
        'LOG_STDOUT': True,
        'LOG_FILE': 'scrapy_log.txt',
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
        'RETRY_ENABLED': True,
        'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 503, 504, 400, 404, 408],
        'RETRY_TIMES': 5
    })
    process.crawl(MyOtherSpider)
    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
except Exception as e:
    print('ERROR while crawling: {}'.format(e))
else:
    print('Data successfuly crawled')
```

When I do this, the first `Crawler` works as expected. But then, the second one creates an empty output file and fails. This also happens if I store the second `CrawlerProcess` into a different variable, such as `process2`. Obviously, I tried changing the order of the Spiders to check if this was a problem of that particular Spider, but the one failing is always the one going the second place.

If I inspect the log file, after the first job is done, it seems that 2 Scrapy bots are started, so maybe something weird is happening:

```
2017-05-29 23:51:41 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (2284 items) in: data\one_origin\20170529.json
2017-05-29 23:51:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2017-05-29 23:51:41 [stdout] INFO: Data successfuly crawled
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOG_FILE': 'scrapy_output.txt', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': 'data\\other_origin\\20170529.json', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)', 'LOG_STDOUT': True, 'RETRY_TIMES': 5, 'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 503, 504, 400, 404, 408], 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3}
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOG_FILE': 'scrapy_output.txt', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': 'data\\other_origin\\20170529.json', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)', 'LOG_STDOUT': True, 'RETRY_TIMES': 5, 'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 503, 504, 400, 404, 408], 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3}
...
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [stdout] INFO: ERROR while crawling:
2017-05-29 23:51:44 [stdout] INFO: ERROR while crawling:
```

Any idea of what's happening and how to fix this?

Comment: You can have a look at my https://stackoverflow.com/a/42512653/2572383, which uses `CrawlerRunner`

Answer (score 1):

Each spider with different settings. Based on [Practices](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) and [Core API](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html).

```
import os
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner, Crawler
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

from spiders import Spider1, Spider2

runner = CrawlerRunner()

def crawl(spider, settings):
    global runner

    crawler = Crawler(spider, settings=settings)
    runner.crawl(crawler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    configure_logging()

    crawl(Spider1, settings={
        'FEED_EXPORTERS': {
            'xlsx': 'scrapy_xlsx.XlsxItemExporter',
        },
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'xlsx',
        'FEED_URI': 'spider1.xlsx'
    })
    crawl(Spider2, settings={
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': 'spider2.json'
    })

    d = runner.join()
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score -1):

Put

```
process.start()
```

At the very end of your script and your both scrapers will run at same time.

**PS:** I already have done this kind of thing.

Here is a little pirce of code I am sharing.

```
batches = 10
while batches > 0:
    process = CrawlerProcess( SETTINGS HERE )
    process.crawl(AmazonSpider())
    batches = batches - 1

process.start() # then finally run your Spiders.
```

Comment: If I do this, then I can't set different settings for each Spider, and I need to do so if I want different output files

Comment: @RomanRdgz see edited code ... I think you can set settings like that